# Show there exists such $x\in F^n$ for some $A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ such $Ax$ has no zero entry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$M_{m\times n}(F)$ is the set of all ${m\times n}$ matrices over field $F$. Now, assume $A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ and $A$ has no zero-rows (rows that all their elements are zero). Also $F$ is an infinite field. Show that there exists an $x\in F^n$ (${n\times1}$ vector) such that none of entries of $Ax$ is zero.

I know about these:

- elementary operations
- row-reduced echelon forms
- linear dependence or independence
- equivalent matrices
- matrix block multiplication

Assume $A=[a_{ij}]$. We know the conditions of problem are satisfied when:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\dots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\dots&a_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\dots&a_{mn}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2\\
\vdots\\
u_m
\end{bmatrix}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(u_i\neq0\text{ for } 1\leq i\leq m)$$

So we should find a vector $x$ that all equations like this are not zero:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n{a_{ij}}x_j\neq 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (0\leq i\leq m)$$

I tried assuming that there's no matrix like this then reach a contradiction, but I couldn't. I also tried to construct the vector $x$ and use linear dependency, but this also didn't give me any thing good. Any help is so much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Use induction. If the last column has any zeros, choose $(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$ inductively to make all of the corresponding rows nonzero.  Then for the remaining rows, we want to choose $x_n = \alpha$ so that $v_i + a_{i,n}\alpha \neq 0$ for all $i$, where $v_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_{ij} x_j$. But if for all $\alpha$ there is some $i$ with $v_i + a_{i,n}\alpha  = 0$, then every $\alpha \in F$ is equal to some $-v_i / a_{i,n}$; but there are only finitely many such  values $-v_i / a_{i,n}$.

Comment: Can you solve any special cases?  E.g. inducting on $m$ and focusing on $\mathbb F:= \mathbb R$  should be straightforward and give you (almost) enough insight to solve the original problem.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Yes, but what next?